# Amazon AWS/EC2 - How to put to servers on same "private network"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new at Amazon AWS/EC2. Basically, I have two EC2 instances set up and running - 2x t2.medium, Windows 2012 servers, etc.

Each server has it's own public and private ip addresses from different subnets:

```
Server 1: 53.171.139.195/171.30.51.181
Server 2: 53.164.26.68/171.30.59.198
```

I simply need these servers to be able to communicate with one another on the same private network.

I see things like elastic ip's, vpc's. Still researching, but I'm not sure what I need. Can this be done and what do I need to configure?

**Update:**
Based on @Bram's response below, I looked at VPC's. Apparently, a default VPC was created when I started my instances.

```
171.30.0.0/16
```

So... Are the on the same subnet by default???

Comment: Those are in the same Virtual Private Cloud (VPC). The VPC is the "private network" you are looking for. A VPC will have multiple subnets, and you shouldn't necessarily want all computers to be in the same subnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a Virtual Private Cloud, a VPC. In a VPC you can create private and public subnets and your instances can be added to those subnets as you like.

Comment: Am I able to use the default VPC that was created when I started up my instances?

Comment: @JohnRussell yes. If you didn't create VPC in your region. Instances will launch automatically in default VPC.